# “Access is denied” on IE browser for browser.min.js in react.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11

[Screenshot of IE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyxba.png) ,[Screenshot of IE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU7TT.png) I am getting error in browser.min.js of Access denied on IE browser for browser.min.js in react.js.

IE gives me the error message "Access denied" while in every other browser I don't notice this behaviour. Since I have tried many things and still cannot imagine where the problem lies I'd like to ask you what you think the problem might be?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Is your site https and the resource http or vice versa?

Comment: it is http.i am attaching screenshot of the error

Comment: If you deselect "Debug just my code" the debugger will break in the external module.... at the call point in your screen shot. 'object' is of type 'Window'... probably it is asking for window.location.... you have set "Break on all exceptions"... try "Break on unhandled exceptions" as the external module probably uses try,catch,finally for browser interoperability with their code. Normally all exceptions are hidden from the user, unless the dev tool is loaded, so for site visitors any external code errors that are handled with try blocks, don't occur.

Comment: i am using break point for unhandled exception attached screenshot of IE2.still not able to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

IE has trouble with some of the babel es6 syntax, so the community has created polyfills to patch needed functionality.

Generally, adding a `require('es6-promise').polyfill();` to my source code fixes that issue. You can seek out other polyfills if that one doesn't do the trick.